# Can not find module 'debug

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I've been having this issue for a while and I've even opened an issue on electron-builder github page but haven't received any response.

I'm running electron builder version 20.38.4 and trying to package the app for Win 64 environment. Everything works fine when I do "yarn dev" and "yarn compile". Even "yarn dist" works without any issue.

However, when I click on the generated .exe file, I get this error message.

Any ideas?

Here's the link to the issue I've opened with some detailed screenshots and log outputs

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3561

Here's the package.json as requested

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev",
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "dist": "yarn compile && electron-builder",
    "dist:dir": "yarn dist --dir -c.compression=store -c.mac.identity=null"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rodrigogs/mysql-events": "^0.5.2",
    "electron-online": "^1.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "3.0.10",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.4",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.teamio.app",
    "productName": "Teamio",
    "buildVersion": "1.0",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Teamio.app",
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Uninstall Teamio"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried upgrading my node to latest version (v10.14.2) and that didn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to revive an old question, but what is happening is the `electron-online` package does not properly define its dependencies in its own `package.json`. So it is missing the `debug` package, which you have "solved" by placing another package that requires `debug` in your project dependencies. In reality though, the (long abandoned) package `electron-online` should update its dependencies and add `debug`, among others.

As a slightly cleaner workaround, you could add `debug` to your project dependencies instead of `electron-webpack` or `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few hours ago, resolved by not excluding (ignoring) the src folder from package config. Could you paste you package.json file here ?

Comment: I've updated with the package.json..let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Looks like I've solved my own problem. Not sure why exactly but it worked. What I had to do was move 2 dependencies listed below from devDependencies to dependencies section in my package.json

```
"electron-webpack": "^2.6.1",
"webpack": "^4.26.0"
```

If someone can shed some light on that, it'd be helpful. I figured I'd post it here in case someone else runs into this issue.